# Makefile: embedded statements

Tags: makefile

I have in the `/bin` folder a file `program.cc`.

The following Makefile statements

```
BINS = $(wildcard bin/*.cc)
EXECS = $(notdir $(BINS))
EXECSR = $(EXECS:.cc=)
```

mean that `EXECSR` is `program`

I try to avoid the intermediary variable `EXECS` in the above statements

```
BINS = $(wildcard bin/*.cc)
EXECSR = $($(notdir $(BINS)):.cc=)
```

but this approach fails - `EXECSR` is empty. How should I modify the Makefile to avoid the intermediary variable `EXECS`?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXECSR = $(notdir $(BINS:.cc=))
```